# Replicate async calls - new Thread() - better approach?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-rest, java-threads

Please excuse me if this question is silly, i am absolutely new to Thread functionality. I am checking, what i ever i am doing is good enough or is there any better approach. Please suggest.

I have a scheduler which invokes every 5 minutes, this pulls ~500+ different records and distributes this data to 6 classes(functionality categorized), these 6 classes intern calls some other external services(Restful Services) to validate the data. So each call takes approximately 5 seconds to process it.

By keeping this issue in mind, to replicate async functionality(fire and forget) i have added anonymous Thread in side the process method of these 6 classes as shown below.

Scheduler may call these 6 classes multiple times with in this 5 minutes.

```
class A {
    public void processMessages(Message message) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            //Restful calls to other external services, this take ~5 seconds to respond.
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are using spring take a look at `@Async` annotation

Comment: You may use an `ExecutorService` here.